# Google Maps API - Problems with class GLatLngBounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having some trouble with the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html). I have an array which holds a ojbect I created to store points.

My array and class:

```
var tPoints = [];    
function tPoint(name) {
        var id = name;
        var points = [];
        var pointsCount = 0;
        ...
        this.getHeadPoint = function() { return points[pointsCount-1]; }
    }
```

tPoint holds an array of [GLatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng) points. I want to write a function to return a [GLatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLngBounds) object which is extended from the current map bounds to show all the HeadPoints.

Heres what I have so far..

```
function getBounds() {
    var mBound = map.getBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < tPoints.length; i++) {
        alert(mBound.getSouthWest().lat() + "," + mBound.getSouthWest().lng());
        alert(mBound.getNorthEast().lat() + "," + mBound.getNorthEast().lng());
            currPoint = trackMarkers[i].getHeadPoint();        
            if (!mBound.containsLatLng(currPoint)) {
                mBound.extend(currPoint);
            }
        }
    return mBound;
}
```

Which returns these values for the alert. (Generally over the US)

> "19.64258,NaN"
>  "52.69636,NaN"
>  "i=0"
>   "19.64258,NaN"
>  "52.69636,-117.20701"
>  "i=1"

I don't know why I am getting NaN back.
When I use the bounds to get a zoom level I think the NaN value is causing the map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds) to return 0 which is incorrect. Am I using [GLatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLngBounds) incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google maps sample is using this code...

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
```

...which is putting the SouthWest/NorthEast bounds into a variable before attempting to get the individual lng/lat coordinates. Maybe there is something with the "nested" evaluations causing problems. Have tried the granular approach to see if you get the data you need?

Answer (score 1):

I found that example through my Google searches too and did play with it. That wasn't the problem.

I found my bug. No one would have been able to solve the problem. It turns out that right before I test my bounds I had centered my map with bad data. I did something like the `lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();` however JavaScript interpreted my var as a string. So `(maxLng-minLng)/2 + minLng` returns something like `"20.456-116.1178"` as the `lng`. I centered my map on `var centerPoint = new GLatLng(setLat, setLng);` and after that the maps API gets a little strange ;)

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, since it was your solution